# Ignore an empty combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have 5 combo boxes, used to filter a listbox. I want to make it so not all 5 have to be selected in order for the filter to work. Each combobox starts blank ( "" ), and I want to be able to skip 1 or several and filter with the ones I select. Here is the AfterUpdate code for one of the comboboxes:

```
On Error Resume Next

    'These are the comboboxes
   Me.BilletMaterial.RowSource = [MechanicalData.Billet Material]
   Me.BilletNumber.RowSource = [MechanicalData.Billet Number]
   Me.TestType.RowSource = [MechanicalData.Test Type]
   Me.Axis.RowSource = [MechanicalData.Axis]
   Me.Temperature.RowSource = [MechanicalData.Temperature]

   Me.BilletMaterial.Requery    
   Me.BilletNumber.Requery
   Me.TestType.Requery
   Me.Axis.Requery
   Me.Temperature.Requery
'Listbox
Me.DataView.RowSource = "SELECT [Billet Material],[Billet Number], " & _
"[Specimen],[Temperature],[Modulus],[Ultimate Tensile Strength],[Strain]  " & _
"FROM MechanicalData " & _
"WHERE 1=1 " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Axis] = '" & Me.Axis.Value & "'  " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Test Type] = '" & TestType.Value & "' " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Temperature] = " & Temperature.Value & " " & _
"AND If (Not IsNull(BilletNumber.Value)) Then [MechanicalData.Billet Number] = " & BilletNumber.Value & " End if  " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Billet Material] = '" & BilletMaterial.Value & "' "
```

My first thought would be to implement multiple "if is not empty..." statements in the WHERE portion of the SELECT statement, but I'm not sure how to do that or even if it's possible.

I know the syntax of this line is wrong.

```
"AND If (Not IsNull(BilletNumber.Value)) Then [MechanicalData.Billet Number] = " & BilletNumber.Value & " End if  " & _
```

Comment: Why not build the WHERE string using `If (Not IsNull(Combo)) Then strWhere = strWhere & `

Comment: @Remou is 'strWhere = strWhere' in your comment equivalent to [MechanicalData.Axis] = '" & Me.Axis.Value & "' " (etc) in my code?

Comment: Yes, just build up the where statemet. You might like to start with `WHERE 1=1` so everything else can be `AND this=that`

Comment: @Remou I added a line of code following your suggestion to the bottom of my post. I am not too familiar with proper syntax yet, so if you could steer me in the right direction for it that would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think you're utilizing the string concatenation properly. It should look something like `AND [MechanicalData.Axis] = " & Me.Axis.Value & " ` .. Single quotes are not needed. Has this actually worked before? Also, when I check for Null values in comboboxes, I used the method Remou described (except I use `If IsNull (Object.Value) = False Then`)

Comment: @Newbie WIthout the single quotes, Access opens a dialog box asking for a parameter. The code I posted originally (without the if) worked

Comment: Really? That's odd. I feel stupid for saying that now. So an option you also have for this type of scenario is to populate the Comboboxes with a row source non programmatically (I'm not sure what kind of data is in your comboboxes) and build `SELECT CASE` statements to handle the user's selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the code you have above is missing the 'FROM MechanicalData' clause.  Using the suggestions from above, the following should work (assuming all combobox values are non-numeric):

```
Dim strWhere    As String

strWhere = " WHERE (1=1)"
If Not IsNull(Axis.Value) Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([MechanicalData.Axis] = '" & Axis.Value & "') "
If Not IsNull(TestType.Value) Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([MechanicalData.Test Type] = '" & TestType.Value & "') "
If Not IsNull(Temperature.Value) Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([MechanicalData.Temperature] = '" & Temperature.Value & "') "
If Not IsNull(BilletNumber.Value) Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([MechanicalData.Billet Number] = '" & BilletNumber.Value & "') "
If Not IsNull(BilletMaterial.Value) Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([MechanicalData.Billet Material] = '" & BilletMaterial.Value & "') "

Me.DataView.RowSource = "SELECT [Billet Material],[Billet Number], " & _
        "[Specimen],[Temperature],[Modulus],[Ultimate Tensile Strength],[Strain] " & _
        "From MechanicalData " & _
        strWhere
```

Comment: The FROM clause is in the code I copy pasted from. Strange. I'll edit it back in. Also, 2 of those comboboxes are numeric

Comment: I just changed the columns in the table I'm filtering to all be text, and whenever I switch from Design view to Form view I get a popup that says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression", but then everything works just fine

Comment: The Rowsource in the property sheet was just being disagreeable. I removed it and everything works smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for any fields that are defined as numeric, just remove the surrounding quotes from the code that builds the WHERE clause...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
'Listbox
Me.DataView.RowSource = "SELECT [Billet Material],[Billet Number], " & _
"[Specimen],[Temperature],[Modulus],[Ultimate Tensile Strength],[Strain]  " & _
"FROM MechanicalData " & _
"WHERE 1=1 " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Axis] = '" & Nz(Me.Axis.Value, '*') & "'  " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Test Type] = '" & Nz(TestType.Value, '*') & "' " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Temperature] = " & Nz(Temperature.Value, '*') & " " & _
"AND If (Not IsNull(BilletNumber.Value)) Then [MechanicalData.Billet Number] = " & BilletNumber.Value & " End if  " & _
"AND [MechanicalData.Billet Material] = '" & Nz(BilletMaterial.Value, '*') & "' "
```

You may have to tweak that to get the right single quote/double quote thing, but using

> Nz(SomeControl.Value, "*")

is definitely a valid way to return all values.